# Managing XML Data in iOS(Swift)

Tags: ios, xml, swift, parsing

I am using Zillow's web-based API to retrieve data about properties.  I am successfully able to get data back using an NSURLSession, however, it is in XML, and I only have experience handling JSON.

How do I organize this data in a more readable form, and more specifically, how do I get the year built (`<yearBuilt>2007</yearBuilt>`) value?

NSURLSession Code:

```
func data_request(){

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        if (error == nil){
            //dataString is our XML data
            let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(dataString)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

dataString (XML data) printed in Console:
`Optional(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SearchResults:searchresults xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/9b53252/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SearchResults="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd"><request><address>12572 Cherokee Ln</address><citystatezip>Galt, CA</citystatezip></request><message><text>Request successfully processed</text><code>0</code></message><response><results><result><zpid>25951952</zpid><links><homedetails>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/12572-Cherokee-Ln-Galt-CA-95632/25951952_zpid/</homedetails><graphsanddata>http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/12572-Cherokee-Ln-Galt-CA-95632/25951952_zpid/#charts-and-data</graphsanddata><mapthishome>http://www.zillow.com/homes/25951952_zpid/</mapthishome><comparables>http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/25951952_zpid/</comparables></links><address><street>12572 Cherokee Ln</street><zipcode>95632</zipcode><city>Galt</city><state>CA</state><latitude>38.299332</latitude><longitude>-121.267781</longitude></address><FIPScounty>6067</FIPScounty><useCode>SingleFamily</useCode><taxAssessmentYear>2015</taxAssessmentYear><taxAssessment>403012.0</taxAssessment><yearBuilt>2007</yearBuilt><lotSizeSqFt>663418</lotSizeSqFt><finishedSqFt>1527</finishedSqFt><bathrooms>2.0</bathrooms><bedrooms>3</bedrooms><totalRooms>6</totalRooms><zestimate><amount currency="USD">390005</amount><last-updated>02/17/2016</last-updated><oneWeekChange deprecated="true"></oneWeekChange><valueChange duration="30" currency="USD">-8580</valueChange><valuationRange><low currency="USD">370505</low><high currency="USD">409505</high></valuationRange><percentile>0</percentile></zestimate><localRealEstate><region name="Galt" id="24831" type="city"><zindexValue>281,700</zindexValue><links><overview>http://www.zillow.com/local-info/CA-Galt/r_24831/</overview><forSaleByOwner>http://www.zillow.com/galt-ca/fsbo/</forSaleByOwner><forSale>http://www.zillow.com/galt-ca/</forSale></links></region></localRealEstate></result></results></response></SearchResults:searchresults><!-- H:004  T:27ms  S:1131  R:Thu Feb 18 16:33:36 PST 2016  B:4.0.25234-master.df01d52~hotfix_pre.361b6ff -->)(lldb)`

XML in more readable format(when viewed in browser):
[image]

Comment: Unless it's changed recently, the built-in NSXMLParser for iOS is SAX parser that requires walking the whole XML structure & 3 delegate methods to 1) find the desired start tag, 2) extract the contents, and 3) find the end tag. There are several 3rd-party DOM parsers that can load the whole file to memory & target specific elements more easily. This article is old, but may still offer some relevant tips: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this link](http://dubinski.org/wpis/easy-xml-parsing-in-swift/)

First, delegate "NSXMLParserDelegate"

Second, Create XML parser and make delegate to own class

Third, use delegated function of `parser` like `didStartElement` for start tag, `foundCharacters` for the content inside your tag.

**Remember to convert your xml string to NSData for the parser to read.**

Comment: This was how I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Lee's answer is correct.  I am only commenting this answer so future users who stumble upon this issue can have relevant code to try out.  Here was my code:

1) Declare NSXMLParserDelegate in class

2) Declare NSXMLParser variable: 
    `var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()`

3) In viewDidAppear 
 `//url_to_request is our URL we are receiving XML data from
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()`

4)Use XMLParser Delegate Methods

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    eName = elementName
    //println(eName)
    if elementName == "yearBuilt" {
        self.yearBuilt = String()
    }
    if elementName == "useCode" {
        self.homeType = String()
    }
    if elementName == "lotSizeSqFt" {
        self.lotSizeSqFt = String()
    }
    if elementName == "finishedSqFt" {
        self.finishedSqFt = String()
    }
    if elementName == "bathrooms" {
        self.bathrooms = String()
    }
    if elementName == "bedrooms" {
        self.bedrooms = String()
    }
    if elementName == "totalRooms" {
        self.bedrooms = String()
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    let data = string!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        //In this example, "yearBuilt", "useCode", etc, are all values within the <> tag.  
        if eName == "yearBuilt" {
            self.yearBuilt += data
            println("Year Built " + self.yearBuilt )
        }
        if eName == "useCode" {
            self.homeType += data
            println("Home Type " + self.homeType )
        }
        if eName == "lotSizeSqFt" {
            self.lotSizeSqFt += data
            println("lotSizeSqFt " + self.lotSizeSqFt )
        }
        if eName == "finishedSqFt" {
            self.finishedSqFt += data
            println("finishedSqFt " + self.finishedSqFt )
        }
        if eName == "bathrooms" {
            self.bathrooms += data
            println("bathrooms " + self.bathrooms )
        }
        if eName == "bedrooms" {
            self.bedrooms += data
            self.bedroomLabel.text = self.bedrooms
            println("bedrooms " + self.bedrooms )
        }

        if eName == "totalRooms" {
            self.totalRooms += data
            println("totalRooms " + self.totalRooms )
        }


    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    self.homeTypeLabel.text = self.homeType


    self.yearBuiltLabel.text = self.yearBuilt
    self.lotSizeLabel.text = self.lotSizeSqFt
    self.finishedSquareFeetLabel.text = self.finishedSqFt
    self.bathroomsLabel.text = self.bathrooms
    self.totalRoomsLabel.text = self.totalRooms



}
```